# Is it possible to only return a promise on a condition === true otherwise wait(try again)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

So i'm using angularJS and`$q` service.  But for simplicity i'm using `$timeout` since it creates a promise.

**Question:**
Is it possible to only return a promise when a conditional has been satisfied?  For this example, I want to wait for `carousel.params.caruselReady` to return true before I move to next `.then`.

```
   $timeout(function(){
      if(Carousel.params.ready()){
        return ready;

      }  

    },0).then(function(ready){
      //...do stuff..//
    }
```

Carousel.params.ready is coming from `Carousel.js` a factory:

```
   //this function gets called everytime a image has been loaded.  when all images are rendered than carousel is ready
   carouselElLoaded: function (result) {
      var count = 1;
      Carousel.params.pageRenderedLength += count;
      if (Carousel.params.pageRenderedLength >= Carousel.params.pageLength) {
        Carousel.params.carouselReady = true;
      }
   },
```

Lastly, carouselElLoad is being called from `wa.pages.js` (a directive)

```
$img.onload = function (e) {
  var self = this;
  $timeout(function () {
        return self;
  }, 0).then(function () {
    Carousel.set.carouselElLoaded(e);
  });
};
```

Currently, I'm using a `$watch` to achieve this but I was wondering if I could accomplish the same w/o a watcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a promise instead of a boolean flag and it will do exactly what you want.

In `Carousel.js` define a promise names isCarouselReady and resolve it once the carousel is ready, your code should like something like this:

```
  // During the initialisation of your factory 
  var carouselDeferred = $q.defer()
  Carousel.params.isCarouselReady = carouselDeferred.promise;

  //this function gets called everytime a image has been loaded.  when all images are rendered than carousel is ready
   carouselElLoaded: function (result) {
      var count = 1;
      Carousel.params.pageRenderedLength += count;
      if (Carousel.params.pageRenderedLength >= Carousel.params.pageLength) {
        carouselDeferred.resolve(/* What ever you'd like here */);
      }
   },
```

Now you all you have to do in order to use it is:

```
Carousel.params.isCarouselReady.then(function() {
  // Your logic
});
```

Your last part would be nicer if it would look something like this:

```
$img.onload = function (e) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    Carousel.set.carouselElLoaded(e);
  });
};
```

Comment: Trying this out.  But it looks (dare I say) "promising".

Comment: Just want to thank you.  This has opened my eyes a ton! I wish I could give you more points.

Comment: You don't need the `$scope.$apply` if you're using a promise since the `.then` will cause an `$evalAsync` anyway that'll schedule a digest. Also - it's probably better to drop the 'is' from the promise name. Other than that - good answer.

Comment: You do need the $apply. please not that this code is not running inside Angular's scope at all, it's inside an event that is raised by the browser once the image is loaded.